# How to create a 'vector movie' out of data?

Tags: data-visualization

What file formats and software could I use to represent vector images over time as an animation, without compromising the advantages of the vector format?

Say I generate data that is best represented as a single point in the plane, moving over time.  I would like to make an animation showing the motion of this point.  One way to do this is to make a sequence of 2D bitmap images and string these together into an AVI file.  But this produces either huge files (orders of magnitude larger than the underlying dataset) or very low quality animations.  A stack of raster images is a very inefficient representation of the data.

A much better representation would be a sequence of [2D *vector* images](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_graphics).  Vector images combine very high fidelity with small file size.  But is it possible to string such images into an animation?  What kind of software could be used to do so, starting from the underlying dataset?

I imagine a tool such as Adobe Flash could be used here, but this seems akin to making scatterplots from scratch in Illustrator: sure, it can be done and will look nice, but this is not how you make scatterplots.  You use R, Excel or MATLAB, and then perhaps retouch the plot in a graphics program.  I'm looking for a similarly efficient solution, but for making dynamic visualizations rather than plots.

Comment: I've voted as off topic. I would suggest you check out http://d3js.org/. Most I've seen currently in stats packages are poor quality series of bitmap images without smooth transitions (causing change blindness).

Comment: @AndyW, could you suggest a more on-topic place to ask my question?

Thanks for the recommendation, I'll definitely look into it!